# Count NaNs when using value_counts() on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I want to count the number of occurrences over two columns of a DataFrame :

```
No Name
1   A  
1   A
5   T
9   V
Nan M
5   T
1   A
```

I expected `df[["No", "Name"]].value_counts()` to give

```
No Name Count
1   A     3
5   T     2
9   V     1
Nan M     1
```

But I am missing the row containing NaN.

Is there a way to include NaNs in value_counts()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `dropna=False`:

```
df.groupby(['No', 'Name'], dropna=False, as_index=False).size()
```

Output:

```
    No Name  size
0  1.0    A     3
1  5.0    T     2
2  9.0    V     1
3  NaN    M     1
```

P.S. Interestingly enough, `pd.Series.value_counts` method also supports `dropna` argument, but `pd.DataFrame.value_counts` method does not

---

**Update** As pointed out in the other answer, `value_counts` now also supports `dropna=False`. This was introduced in v1.3.0, which was released after my original answer was posted

Comment: However this doesn't give me a dataframe. I want a dataframe with three coulmns as mentioned above.

Comment: @Pete You're right, sorry, just add `as_index=False`. Updated my answer

Comment: @Pete Great! Could you please accept the answer then?

Comment: Of course! I have to wait for like 2 minutes before I can do that. I think there is a time duration after which we can accept.

Answer (score 36):

You can still use value_counts() but with dropna=False rather than True (the default value), as follows:

```
df[["No", "Name"]].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

So, the result will be as follows:

```
   No   Name    size
0   1     A     3
1   5     T     2
2   9     V     1
3   NaN   M     1
```